# Integration by parts not integrating with respect to wrong variable?

Tags: calculus, integration

Integration by parts can be expressed in terms of differentials like so:

$$\int u \, \mathrm{d}v = uv - \int v \, \mathrm{d}u$$

With $u=f(x)$ and $v=g(x)$, and their differentials $\mathrm{d}u = f'(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}v = g'(x)\mathrm{d}x$.

What I don't get is that, considering these are differentials, how can you integrate a variable $u$ with respect to $v$ on the left hand side of the above statement, and integrate $v$ with respect to $u$ on the right hand side.

This is not a question about the integration by parts method in general, as I understand that. The issue is that I recall from integration by substitution that sometimes you'd have to "back-substitute" your leftover $x$-variables (i.e., express them in terms of u) in the integrand so as not to end up with an expression like $\int (x^4u) \mathrm{d}u$, which can't be determined.

How is it then correct to have an expression such as $\int v \, \mathrm{d}u$ wherein you've got two different variables?

Comment: U and V are not variables. $\int u\,\mathrm{d}v= \int f(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Are they not though? They're substitutions according to the Substitution rule, and as you're integrating with respect to a variable v, they gotta be. Otherwise the integral is ill-defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is just a matter of notation.

Let me rewrite the formula using two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

$$\int f(x)g'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(x)g(x) - \int g(x)f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable functions.